# Question mark or a full stop?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

What should be the punctuation at the end? Should it be a question mark or a full stop? Please explain.

> Have you ever got involved so much in a book that you could hear their voices in your head; you could imagine the whole scene in front of your eyes and it feels magical

Comment: Your "punctuation error" is just that you've used a semicolon instead of a question mark at the end of the *actual* question being asked.

Comment: ...also note that the pairing ***could** imagine + **feels** magical* is at the very least an "awkward" clash of tenses. I suggest you use either ***could + felt*** or ***can + feels***.

Comment: Also another punctuation error towards the end is that you put two independent clauses together with an and but no comma; *it* is a noun and marks the start of a new independent clause.

Comment: I'd stay away from 'fancy' punctuation like semicolons until you have mastered more basic things like tense agreement.

Comment: Thanks very much @FumbleFingers for the reply. Wouldn't it be a case of comma splice, if I use a comma instead of a semi colon to join two independent sentences?

Comment: @Shivam: Sure - call using a comma instead of a period a "comma splice" if it helps you. But it's just part of the general trend towards "leaner" punctuation, same as reduced use of commas generally (where using *more* of them to replace even stronger punctuation marks such as periods effectively "bucks the trend"). But my point was *in your specific context*, this has led you into problems regarding what to do about the question mark. When you're in a hole, don't just stop digging. Climb back out and find a different way of getting round the problem!

Comment: *Have you ever got involved so much in a book that you could hear the voices in your head? that you could imagine the whole scene in front of your eyes that it feels magical?* This is how I'd punctuate it. I didn't really like *their voices* so I changed it to *the voices*.

Answer (score 4):

How about a comma.  If you are uncertain, uncomplicate your sentence structure and put a question mark at the end of your question. Even then it's still a bit awkward.

> "Were you ever so involved in a book that you could hear the voices in your head, imagining the whole magical scene in front of your eyes?"

Or even better just compound it.  Smooth....

> "Were you ever so involved in a book that you could hear the voices in your head and imagine the whole magical scene in front of your eyes?"

Comment: Thank you very much @Elliek. I get these sentences, but can't we use a semi colon and start the next independent with "you could imagine"...?

Comment: @Shivam It doesn’t make much sense to use a semicolon there because you are using the same subject and setting for both clauses; it works better to use @EllieK’s method

Comment: Thanks very much Sean. Could you explain what if we have to two independent clauses and we join them with a coordinating conjunction, where the first one is an assertive sentence and the second one is an interrogative sentence, then what would be the final punctuation?

Comment: My takeaway is that to use question point if the main clause is a question, no matter how long the subordinate is.